# how to get specific tag elements from a page using python requests library

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to get all the 'a' tags which are used for links and also the the 'form' tag. The code that I have written fetches the whole page.

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

for url in ['http://www.example.com', 'http://mail.example.com']:
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)

        # If the response was successful, no Exception will be raised
        response.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError as http_err:
        print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')  # Python 3.6
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')  # Python 3.6
    else:
        response.encoding = 'utf-8' # Optional: requests infers this internally
        print(response.text)
```

I can use regular expressions to get a specific thing from the page, but I don't know how to get the entire contents of a particular tag.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: The code in the question was copied from here: https://realpython.com/python-requests/

Answer (score 4):

You can use BeautifulSoup to parse html page:

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for url in ['http://www.example.com', 'http://mail.example.com']:
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)

        # If the response was successful, no Exception will be raised
        response.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError as http_err:
        print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')  # Python 3.6
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')  # Python 3.6
    else:
        response.encoding = 'utf-8' # Optional: requests infers this internally
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        links = soup.find_all('a')
        forms = soup.find_all('form')
```

To install BeautifulSoup use:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: Upvote for the use of `else` in Exception handling.